# Need checkbox with label delete function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of check boxes with labels. You will check any checkbox and click delete button, that checkbox & label should be deleted.

My code will delete checkbox only, that corresponding label not deleted. I need to delete the both checkbox and label.
My code is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label>Do you like summer?</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label>Do you like winter?</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label>Do you like both</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" /><label>other</label><br>
<button>delete</button>

<script>

    $("button").click(function () {
     $("#"+$(":checked").remove());
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What do you think `$("#"+$(":checked").remove())` is doing? Why do you concatenate the return value of `$(":checked").remove()` with `#` and pass this to jQuery? This really makes no sense.

Comment: can you modify the html to add the attribute "for" to the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do:

```
   $("button").click(function () {
       var c = $(":checked");
       c.next('label').remove();
       c.remove()
    });
```

If you want to remove also the `<br>` you could do:

```
   $("button").click(function () {
       var c = $(":checked");
       c.nextUntil(':checkbox').not('button').remove();
       c.remove()
    });
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nUjHN/

Comment: careful, with that solution you need to have the label always after the checkbox!

Answer (score 1):

Those checkboxes don't have labels. A label should have the `for="checkX"` attribute to be linked to checkbox. 
If you do that, it makes it easier too, to select the label for a checkbox, because you can write a selector like this:

```
$("label[for='check1']").remove();
```

Of course you van find the label, as demonstrated in Nicola Peluchetti's answer, but it's better to give the label a 'for' attribute. It improves accessability to your website too. It is actually the purpose of a label to be linked to an input element. Without this link, you could have used a `span` just as well.

[Edit]

Asking for A, B, Both or None is pretty confusing when using checkboxes. You could do with just A and B, or you could use radiobuttons. Now, someone could select both 'A' and 'Both'.